# How to obtain list of requirements for Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, package, dependencies

I am trying to install the Python package Selenium on a machine. However, that machine is on a closed network with no Internet access, and so I have to request each package to be installed one-by-one by IT. So they installed Selenium, but afterwards I found that it doesn't run because it imports other packages that aren't on the system. How do I determine the full list of packages it needs?

Online I find a lot of similar questions which keep pointing to "requirements.txt", but I have no idea where that file is located. It isn't anywhere in the source folder, nor is it on the website where I downloaded the source from (https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Out of genuine curiosity, what would you be using selenium for without internet access? I've only ever used it for web scrapping and navigation, but I wasn't aware of other uses. Or is it something super obvious like preparing the computer for someone else?

Comment: @Omnishroom that's a fair question. The computer is on a closed network which has some websites hosted from a local server. The task is going to use Selenium to scrape those web pages.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have selenium installed. If so, find `.whl` for  the selenium location

```
pip show -f selenium-*.whl
```

This will display information about the package, including its dependencies.

If not, download it without installing

```
pip download --no-deps --no-install selenium
```

This  should get you to download on the internet access machine

Comment: About the second suggestion, am I understanding correctly that it will download all the dependencies at once, and that can be installed in a fell swoop? That would be infinitely more convenient than requesting IT for each package one by one, since I don't know how many packages that would end up being